# Can I have one alias for two distinct members of my enum

Tags: python, enums, python-3.8

I sincerely hope, that I followed all the rules and guidelines and that my question/problem is comprehensive enough to find an adequate answer. First, a small intro:
For a current project of mine I want to designate specific types to tree node objects. To keep matters simple here, I will use colours as an analogy.

### What I have

Let's suppose I have the following enum, derived from the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) standard library:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Colour(Enum):
  CRIMSON = auto()
  SCARLET = auto()
  RED = auto()
  BLUE = auto()
```

So each member has a different value.

### What I want

So far, so good. But what I would *like* to have is this:

```py
class Colour(Enum):
  CRIMSON = auto()
  SCARLET = auto()
  # RED = CRIMSON or SCARLET
  BLUE = auto()
```

So if I have an object with an attribute like this:

```ipython
>>> r = Colour.SCARLET
```

I want the following statements to return `True`:

```ipython
>>> type(r) is Colour
True
>>> r is Colour.SCARLET
True
>>> r is Colour.RED
True
```

and of course this should be `False`:

```ipython
>>> r is Colour.CRIMSON
False
>>> r is Colour.BLUE # obviously False...
False
```

Note that it is not neccessary in my case to be able to assign the type `RED`, only assigning `CRIMSON` or `SCARLET` would be sufficient.

### My current (unsatisfying) solution

What I tried so far is the following:

```py
class Colour(Enum):
# ... member definitions ...
  def isRed(self):
    return self is Colour.SCARLET or self is Colour.CRIMSON
```

But I find this solution rather inelegant and quite a hassle to use. Also it does not reflect the nature of `CRIMSON` and `SCARLET` as shades of `RED`.

Another solution I implemented involved subcalssing or nesting `Colour` but in either case I was not able to meet all the criteria above, hence I refrained from posting these here.

Before I used enums, I represented the `Node.colour` property for each node with integers:

```py
# trees.py
# defining global constants
SCARLET = 1
CRIMSON = 2
BLUE = -1

class Node:
  def __init__(self, parent, children, col):
    self.parent = parent
    self.children = children
    self.colour = col # either 1, 2 or -1
```

So I could do the following:

```ipython
>>> x = Node(None, None, SCARLET)
>>> y = Node(None, None, BLUE)
>>> If x.colour is > 0:# do stuff...
```

but I found that way very unpythonic and rather unintutive as well, since testing for `RED`, `SCARLET`, `BLUE` etc. occurs rather often and this makes the code somewhat harder to read.
Also one should not use `int` data-type if not necessary in my opinion since these "colours" have no natural ordering or other `int`-like properties.

Comment: Do you need `r is Colour.RED` or  also `r == Colour.RED` would suffice?

Comment: Yes, `==` should suffice for the case `RED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure I understand:

```
Colour.SCARLET is Color.RED
Colour.CRIMSON is color.RED
```

but

```
Colour.SCARLET is not Colour.CRIMSON
```

?

If that is correct, then no, you cannot have that.  The reason is that `is` is object identity, and there are no work-arounds or tricks to fool it.  This is intrinsic to Python, not specific to Enums.

Can `SCARLET` and `CRIMSON` be aliases of `RED`, or do they have unique properties, one of which is being a red shade?

Something that might work for you (shown using the [`aenum` library](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/), but doable with slightly more work using the stdlib Enum):

```
from aenum import Enum, auto

class PrimaryColour(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    GREEN = auto()
    BLUE = auto()

class Shades(Enum):
    #
    _init_ = 'value primary'
    #
    CRIMSON = PrimaryColour.RED
    SCARLET = PrimaryColour.RED
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Shades)
[<Shades.CRIMSON: 1>, <Shades.SCARLET: 2>]

>>> Shades.CRIMSON.primary is PrimaryColour.RED
True
```

---

Another possibility:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Colour(Enum):
    #
    RED = auto()
    GREEN = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
    CRIMSON = RED
    SCARLET = RED
    AQUAMARINE = GREEN, BLUE
    #
    def is_colour(self, colour):
        return colour._value_ in self.ancestors or self._value_ in colour.ancestors
    #
    def __new__(cls, *values):
        members = list(cls)
        used_values = {m.value: m for m in members}
        # previous values are now in used_values; after isolating first
        # value, check if it has already been used
        first, *others = values
        if first in used_values:
            # it's an alias -- create a new value
            others = (first, ) + tuple(others)
            first = len(members) + 1
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = first
        member.ancestors = (first, ) + tuple(others)  # always it's own ancestor
        return member
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Colour)
[<Colour.RED: 1>, <Colour.GREEN: 2>, <Colour.BLUE: 3>, <Colour.CRIMSON: 4>, <Colour.SCARLET: 5>, <Colour.AQUAMARINE: 6>]

>>> Colour.RED
<Colour.RED: 1>

>>> Colour.CRIMSON
<Colour.CRIMSON: 4>

>>> Colour.AQUAMARINE
<Colour.AQUAMARINE: 6>

>>> Colour.CRIMSON.is_colour(Colour.RED)
True

>>> Colour.RED.is_colour(Colour.CRIMSON)
True

>>> Colour.CRIMSON.is_colour(Colour.SCARLET)
False
```

Comment: Yes, to the first part, that is indeed the point. Very disappointing that it does not seem possible (you are the author of [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) and [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/), right? I read your name alot while I was researching this.)

I will test your suggestion a little bit, and see how my current implementation compares to it. Thanks so far, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I skipped over your other question, mea culpa! Yes, I was imagining that `CRIMSON` and `SCARLET` are aliases of `RED`, or specifically vice versa: `RED` being one alias for both. Also each colour does not have any other properties and one tree node is either `BLUE` xor `RED`, and if it's `RED` it will be `SCARLET` xor `CRIMSON`.
 I also edited my question above and gave an example of an earlier implementation without using enums, just to sketch the problem more precisely.

Comment: @TiFe: I added another option that might work better.

Comment: That second option looks very promising and close to perfect.
I currently don't have time to test it out extensively/ understand it , but I might do that this weekend.
Thanks so much so far, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I implemented your second version, and was very satisfied.
So I accepted your answer.

But in the actual project, I used one of my own workarounds, since another implementation would've cost to much time for refactorization, which I didn't have at the time.

Comment: @TiFe: I'm happy it helped.  Can you share your actual implementation in a separate answer?  I'm sure that would help somebody down the line.

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment. But I will try to do that as soon as possible. I hope it's not too urgent. Thanks again!